# Is there any reason why the robots were buried and forgotten?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If I can remember right, no reason is given in Zelda: Breath of the wild as to why the robots that were used to defeat Ganon 10000 years ago were then buried and forgotten by pretty much everybody.

Did the sheikah from 10000 years ago see the "Ganon hacking everything" plan coming, or was their use done so they just let them get buried over time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While nothing is concrete, it appears that the Sheikah either A: Became outcasts and were feared by the Hylian people or B: Adhered to the royal family's warning, and forgot their creations and left them to be buried.

> "Eventually, however, people began to fear Sheikah technology being misused, causing the Sheikah to either become outcasts, or follow the Royal Family's warnings by burying their technology and living much simpler lives."

[(The quote came from here)](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Sheikah)